# Creating a cmd script to save bitlocker numeric id to ad

Tags: cmd, active-directory, bitlocker

I am trying to create a bat file to run cmd code to save bitlockers numeric id to ad
the code I got that far is

````
@echo off
title bitlocker to AD.
echo Bitlocker to ActiveDirectory
pause
powershell -Command manage-bde -protectors -get c:
powershell -Command manage-bde -protectors c: -id {<numericalpassword>}
echo 1)Exit
set input=
set /p input= Choice
if %input%==2 goto Exit if NOT goto Start 2```
`

But what I got when I run it is:  
[![what really happened][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM3b9.png

basically it cannot recognize the "<numericalpassword>"

How to I get the numerical password id as a string that I can push to the second line?
````

Comment: Use quotations marks (`'`) instead of curly brackets around the password/id

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

> how to i get the numerical password id as a string that i can push to
> the second line ?

You can use the below command to get the numerical password id as a string variablee :

```
$key = ((manage-bde -protectors -get c:) | Select-String -SimpleMatch "ID: ")[1] -replace "ID:","" -replace " ",""
```

[image]

Now you can use this variable in the second line as follows :

```
manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id $key
```

Also, you can write the powershell script for the two powershell commands and run the script in the bat file.

Use the below powershell script :

```
$key = ((manage-bde -protectors -get c:) | Select-String -SimpleMatch "ID: ")[1] -replace "ID:","" -replace " ",""
manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id $key
```

Save this script in your local and use this line in your bat file :

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'path-to-your-powershell-script'"
```

Instead of

```
powershell -Command manage-bde -protectors -get c:
powershell -Command manage-bde -protectors c: -id {<numericalpassword>}
```

Comment: Unfortunatlly I cannot run this line in cmd

Comment: that is a powershell command. Are  you not able  to run it in bat file?

Comment: I edited  the answer on how to make it as a powershell script and use it in bat  file

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this when I try to run:

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'path-to-your-powershell-script'"

Output:

C:\Users>$key = ((manage-bde -protectors -get c:)   | Select-String -SimpleMatch "ID: ")[1] -replace "ID:","" -replace " ",""
'$key' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32726293)